# todo list bootsrtarp

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Дела по умолчанию выполнены. При нажатии на кнопку "готово", дело не удаляется. Помогите пж, сижу уже месяц. Админу добра, ответчику банку пива!

```
(function () {
    // Создаём и возвращаем заголовок приложения
    function createAppTitle(title) {
        let appTitle = document.createElement('h2');
        appTitle.innerHTML = title;
        //console.log(appTitle);
        return appTitle;
    }

    // Создаём и возвращаем форму для создания дела
    function createTodoItemForm() {
        let form = document.createElement('form');
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        let buttonWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        let button = document.createElement('button');

        form.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3');
        input.classList.add('form-control');
        input.placeholder = 'Введите название нового дела';
        buttonWrapper.classList.add('input-group-append');
        button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
        button.textContent = 'Добавить дело';
        button.disabled = true;

        buttonWrapper.append(button);
        form.append(input);
        form.append(buttonWrapper);

        input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value.length > 0) {
                button.disabled = false;
            } else if (input.value.length == 0) {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        });

        return {
            form,
            input,
            button,
        };
    }

    // Создаём и возвращаем список элементов
    function createTodoList() {
        let list = document.createElement('ul');
        list.classList.add('list-group');
        return list;
    }

    function createTodoItem(title, name, done, add) {
        let item = document.createElement('li');
        // Кнопки помещаем в элемент, который красиво покажет их в одной группе
        let buttonGroup = document.createElement('div');
        let doneButton = document.createElement('button');
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

        // Устанавливаем стили для элемента сиписка, а так же для размещения кнопок
        // в его правой части с помощью flex
        item.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
        item.textContent = name;
        item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success');
        done = doneButton;

        buttonGroup.classList.add('btn-group', 'btn-group-sm');
        doneButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-success');
        doneButton.textContent = 'Готово';
        deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger');
        deleteButton.textContent = 'Удалить';

        // Вкладываем кнопки в отдельный элемент, чтобы они объединились в один блок
        buttonGroup.append(doneButton);
        buttonGroup.append(deleteButton);
        item.append(buttonGroup);

        // добавляем в массив новое дело
     if (add) arrayCases.push({ caseTitle: name, done: true/false })
     //Наполняем localStorage
     window.localStorage.setItem(title, JSON.stringify(arrayCases))
    //console.log(window.localStorage.getItem(title, JSON.stringify(arrayCases)));


        // Приложению нужен доступ к самому элементу и кнопкам, чтобы обрабатывать события нажатия
        return {
            item,
            doneButton,
            done,
            deleteButton,
            title:name,
        };
    }
    //console.log(container);
    function createTodoApp(container, title = 'Список дел', arrayCases = []) {
        //console.log(title);

        let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title);
        //console.log(todoAppTitle);
        let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
        let todoList = createTodoList();
        //console.log(todoAppTitle);
        //console.log(container);
        container.append(todoAppTitle);
        container.append(todoItemForm.form);
        container.append(todoList);

        console.log(arrayCases);

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayCases.length; i++) {
            console.log(arrayCases['caseTitle']);
            var gi = createTodoItem(arrayCases[i]['name'],arrayCases[i]['done']);
            console.log(i)
            console.log(arrayCases[i]['title'])
            console.log(arrayCases[i]['done'])
            console.log(gi)
            todoList.append(gi.item);
        }
        //console.log(todoList)

        // Браузер создаёт событие submit на форме по нажатию на Enter или на кнопку создания дела
        todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            // Эта строчка необходима, чтобы предотвратить стандартное действие браузера
            // В данном случае мы не хотим, чтобы страница перезагружалась при отправке формы
            e.preventDefault();

            // Игнорируем создание элемента, если пользователь ничего не ввел в поле
            if (!todoItemForm.input.value) {
                return;
            }
            //console.log(title);
            let todoItem = createTodoItem(title, todoItemForm.input.value, false, true);

            // Добавляем обработчики на кнопку
            todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-sucess');
            });
            todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                if (confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
                    todoItem.item.remove();
                }
            });

            // Создаём и добавляем в список новое дело с названием из поля для ввода
            todoList.append(todoItem.item);

            // Обнуляем значение в поле, чтобы не пришлось стирать его вручную
            todoItemForm.input.value = '';

            window.localStorage.setItem(title, JSON.stringify(arrayCases));
            arrayCases.splice(i)

        });
    }

    window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp;
})();
```

Comment: То есть ты этооо всёёё написал, но не можешь удаление сделать?))

Comment: Пробуй отладку и искать ошибки (ссылка сверху). Это может помочь